# Jobs for nfs-server.service canceled

Tags: rhel, nfs

I am trying to setup an NFS server but after starting the service it is showing this error;

```
Job for nfs-server.service canceled.
```

This is my configuration file (`/etc/exports`)

```
/fold1  192.168.43.226
```

Error message:

```
● nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/nfs-server.service.d
           └─order-with-mounts.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-09-28 19:27:13 IST; 40s ago
  Process: 18660 ExecStopPost=/usr/sbin/exportfs -f (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 18656 ExecStopPost=/usr/sbin/exportfs -au (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 18654 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/exportfs -r (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 28 19:27:13 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting NFS server and services...
Sep 28 19:27:13 localhost.localdomain exportfs[18654]: exportfs: Failed to stat /fold1: No such file or directory
Sep 28 19:27:13 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 28 19:27:13 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 28 19:27:13 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped NFS server and services.
```

I am using Red Hat 8.

Comment: It might be good if you gave the full error output for the job, not just that it was cancelled.

Comment: @jsbillings Done!

Comment: Did you see the error message that read:  `exportfs: Failed to stat /fold1: No such file or directory`?

Comment: @jsbillings yes I read that, but i have that folder in my home directory

Comment: Could you add the output of `ls -ld /fold1/` to your question?

Answer (score 2):

In case this helps someone in the future:

I had the same error message setting up NFS on a Raspberry Pi running raspbian (a Debian Buster derivative), despite having felt I was following instructions precisely.

Running "sudo systemctl" by itself showed me a list of services, and showed that "nfs-server.service" had loaded but failed to run.

What solved it for me was to remove white space from the /etc/exports file lines: e.g.

```
/nfs/share  192.168.1.200/24(rw,nohide,insecure,no_subtree_check,async)
```

instead of the line I had originally typed:

```
/nfs/share  192.168.1.200/24(rw, nohide, insecure, no_subtree_check, async)
```

This occurred to me after reading about some else having the issue when they copy-pasted the lines rather than manually typed them.

No more error message and 'sudo systemctl' showed that the service is now up and running.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This may have different reasons for failure, it is better to check the log first, the default log of it should in `/var/log/messages`. For easy debugging it, you could try to trace the log like `tail -f /var/log/messages`, then start another terminal do like: `sudo systemctl start nfs-server`. In my case, I can find the issue of

> exportfs: Failed to stat /var/nfs/mynfs: No such file or directory

Then just fix it by creating this file.

Comment: It worked when I added full path of the folder

Comment: I couldn't find the log messages (/var/log/messages) to resolve this. What to do next?